# Should I use _T or _TEXT on C++ string literals?

Tags: c++, winapi, backwards-compatibility, literals

For example:

```
// This will become either SomeMethodA or SomeMethodW,
// depending on whether _UNICODE is defined.
SomeMethod( _T( "My String Literal" ) );

// Becomes either AnotherMethodA or AnotherMethodW.
AnotherMethod( _TEXT( "My Text" ) );
```

I've seen both. _T seems to be for brevity and _TEXT for clarity. Is this merely a subjective programmer preference or is it more technical than that? For instance, if I use one over the other, will my code not compile against a particular system or some older version of a header file?

Comment: Should this have a visual-c++ tag on it, or is _T() common among implementations?

Comment: There is also a `TEXT` macro (no leading underscore) from the Windows header files. The fourth (and shortest) alternative is to use “wide” strings (`L"…"`) everywhere—Windows 98/Me isn’t widely used any more.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A simple grep of the SDK shows us that the answer is that **it doesn't matter—they are the same**.  They both turn into `__T(x)`.

```
C:\...\Visual Studio 8\VC>findstr /spin /c:"#define _T(" *.h 
crt\src\tchar.h:2439:#define _T(x)       __T(x) 
include\tchar.h:2390:#define _T(x)       __T(x)

C:\...\Visual Studio 8\VC>findstr /spin /c:"#define _TEXT(" *.h 
crt\src\tchar.h:2440:#define _TEXT(x)    __T(x) 
include\tchar.h:2391:#define _TEXT(x)    __T(x)
```

And for completeness:

```
C:\...\Visual Studio 8\VC>findstr /spin /c:"#define __T(" *.h 
crt\src\tchar.h:210:#define __T(x)     L ## x 
crt\src\tchar.h:889:#define __T(x)      x 
include\tchar.h:210:#define __T(x)     L ## x 
include\tchar.h:858:#define __T(x)      x
```

However, *technically*, for C++ you should be using `TEXT()` instead of `_TEXT()`, but it (eventually) expands to the same thing too.

Comment: Interesting.  Not only are they the same, they are defined in the same header.  I had the mistaken assumption that _TEXT was Win32 and _T was ATL.

Comment: @Max: They are also define, oddly, in MAPINls.h and MAPIWin.h, but I'm not sure why, and I excluded those from the results above for simplicity.  But yeah, they're not ATL things they're Win32 things.  It's possible the ATL documentation uses it because they liked it better?  ATL is all about saving you typing right?  :)

Comment: `TEXT` and `_TEXT` are different if `UNICODE` is defined but `_UNICODE` is not  (they correspond respectively)

Answer (score 21):

Commit to Unicode and just use `L"My String Literal"`.

Comment: Converting to Unicode is not necessarily possible at the moment you're writing a piece of code.  In the meantime, using _T() means nobody will have to change your code when it is converted.

Comment: If you are committed to MS, then fabulous.  Use all of their fancy macros and language extensions.  Using `_T` means *somebody* will have to change your code when it is converted *to any other platform*.  Only unsuccessful software is never ported...

Comment: If you're writing _new_ code (even in an old codebase), there's absolutely no excuse to not always use `L""`. Another habit is to explicitly call wide functions, i.e. use `MessageBoxW` rather than `MessageBox` etc - it ensures that code will work the same regardless of how it's compiled. Remember that all MS OSes that didn't support Unicode APIs out of the box are already unsupported. Also, non-Unicode versions are less efficient on any NT OS. Don't forget MSLU / `UnicoWS.dll` for those cases when you need to support 9x, which lets you keep using Unicode even there.

Comment: There's no portability issue here. If he has functions defined via macro which expands either to `FuncA` or `FuncW` depending on `_UNICODE`, we're likely talking about Win32 API calls here already. I'm not aware of any stock C/C++ APIs that do anything like that.

Comment: I was going to say that he's already tied to Win32, which of course has to be addressed if the code is to be ported, but the text macros are an *ADDITIONAL* thing to deal with.  Just because one aspect is not portable doesn't mean all bets are off.

Comment: @STingRaySC: `_T` doesn't tie you to Microsoft at all. `#define _T(x) L##x` and you're done.

Comment: If we were to port our current codebase to Linux, _T() would be one of the least of our worries.  It's the work of a moment to write a replacement macro.  Converting from MFC to something else would take far more time.

Comment: @Mark: but it creates extra work for no benefit.  Of course it could be defined, but getting that into every translation unit is not necessarily trivial.  And then it just becomes cruft.

Comment: @STingRaySC: You should have a porting header. Mark's right, but it should be TEXT not _TEXT, and define to _TEXT on MS, since it's a reserved name. Then on platforms which support Unicode but where the APIs you want to use take UTF-8, you don't need a conversion. If you commit to wide-char strings, your code is less easily portable for use with unknown future OS calls, not more.

Comment: Nice sentiment, but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It *DOES* answer the question. No, you should not use _T or _TEXT on C++ string literals!

Comment: Maybe I should ask another question about whether to support both `SomeMethodA` and `SomeMethodW` or strictly `SomeMethodW` (implying that L should be put in front of all strings)?

Comment: If you are using Unicode (wide) string literals, as you should be, you will never need to use/support the ...A functions.

Comment: @Pavel: thanks for the -1.  I was trying not to open that can of worms.  It's not relevant to the question.  It should be a conscious decision to use either chars or wide chars for every string literal.  And since MS defines Unicode as UTF-16, wide chars are a necessity.

Comment: @Mark: No, you aren't done if you `#define _T(x) L##x`.  The whole point of `TCHAR` is to deal with all the Windows functions being duplicated for ANSI and UTF-16 versions.  Other platforms don't have that.

Comment: @dan04, there may be many things that tie a program to Windows. My point is that `_T` isn't one of them, so there's no specific reason to avoid it.

Comment: Since most (?) other operating systems use 8-bit characters (i.e., UTF-8 encoding) exclusively, surely using _T instead of L"" actually makes porting *easier*?

Answer (score 17):

From [Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040212-00/?p=40643):

> TEXT vs. _TEXT vs. _T, and UNICODE vs. _UNICODE
>
> The plain versions without the
> underscore affect the character set
> the Windows header files treat as
> default. So if you define UNICODE,
> then GetWindowText will map to
> GetWindowTextW instead of
> GetWindowTextA, for example.
> Similarly, the TEXT macro will map to
> L"..." instead of "...".
>
> The versions with the underscore
> affect the character set the C runtime
> header files treat as default. So if
> you define _UNICODE, then _tcslen will
> map to wcslen instead of strlen, for
> example. Similarly, the _TEXT macro
> will map to L"..." instead of "...".
>
> What about _T? Okay, I don't know
> about that one. Maybe it was just to
> save somebody some typing.

Short version: `_T()` is a lazy man's `_TEXT()`

Note: You need to be aware of what code-page your source code text editor is using when you write:

```
_TEXT("Some string containing Çontaining");
TEXT("€xtended characters.");
```

The bytes the compiler sees depends on the code page of your editor.

Answer (score 8):

[Here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040212-00/?p=40643)'s an interesting read from a well-known and respected source.

> Similarly, the _TEXT macro will map to L"..." instead of "...".
>
> What about _T? Okay, I don't know about that one. Maybe it was just to save somebody some typing.

Comment: You left out a key bit: _TEXT("hello") == L"hello" ONLY if UNICODE is defined.

And yes, _T("hello") is just an abbreviation.

Comment: Both `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` should always be defined unless you're planning a time travel to the nineties.

Answer (score 5):

I've never seen anyone use `_TEXT()` instead of `_T()`.

Answer (score 5):

These macros are a hold over from the days when an application might have actually wanted to compile both a unicode and ANSI version.

There is no reason to do this today - this is all vestigial. Microsoft is stuck with supporting every possible configuration forever, but you aren't. If you are not compiling to both ANSI and Unicode (and no one is, let's be honest) just go to with L"text".

And yes, in case it wasn't clear by now: _T == _TEXT

Answer (score 4):

Neither.  In my experience there are two basic types of string literals, those that are invariant, and those that need to be translated when your code is localized.

It's important to distinguish between the two as you write the code so you don't have to come back and figure out which is which later.

So I use `_UT()` for untranslatable strings, and `ZZT()` (or something else that is easy to search on) for strings that will need to be translated.  Instances of `_T()` or `_TEXT()` in the code are evidence of string literals that have not yet be correctly categorized.

`_UT` and `ZZT` are both #defined to _TEXT

Comment: You should have a better system for localizing the strings than search/replace.

Comment: I like that idea.  I've had enough trouble figuring out which strings are displayed to the user (and hence should be translated) and which go to log files (which should not be).

Comment: @Mark: What makes you think I don't?

Comment: I miss the days of ZZT... I digress.

Answer (score -5):

Use neither, and also please don't use the L"..." crap.
Use UTF-8 for all strings, and convert them just before passing to microsoft APIs.

Comment: The worst possible option on Windows, will require millions of unnecessary string conversions. Always use UTF-16.

Comment: Disagree categorically. See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049947/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful why UTF-16 is bad on windows.

Comment: Should UTF-16 be considered harmful? - https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/102205/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful

Comment: well, utf8everywhere.org