# Cast Operator with template class

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2005

I want to overload a cast operator,
I have the following piece of code :

```
template <typename _T>
class CTest
{
public :
    _T data;

    CTest(_T _data) : data(_data) {}
    ~CTest() {}

    operator _T(){ return data; }
};
```

And MS Visual Studio 2005, give me the following errors :

> warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro '*T'
>   warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro '*_T'
>   error C2833: 'operator L' is not a recognized operator or type
>   see reference to class template instantiation 'CTest<_T>' being compiled
>   error C2059: syntax error : 'newline'
>   error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
>   error C2833: 'operator L' is not a recognized operator or type

How can I declare **operator _T()** correctly ?

Comment: Names with leading underscore are reserved for the implementation. You've stumbled on one. Just remove the underscores and it'll compile.

Comment: Particularly leading underscore followed by a capital letter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_T` is a WINAPI macro (see [Generic-Text Mappings in Tchar.h](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or [Should I use _T or _TEXT on C++ string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074579/should-i-use-t-or-text-on-c-string-literals)): change `_T` to `T`.