# What is TEXT("xxx") in C++?

Tags: c++, string, winapi, text

I see the following code:

```
    UINT uiStat =  MsiGetProperty(hInstall, TEXT("MyProperty"), TEXT(""), &cchValueBuf);
```

What is the meaning of TEXT("xxx")?

Thanks

**Update:**

The codesnippet comes from the following URL:

https://documentation.help/Windows-Installer/msigetproperty.htm

Comment: Where do you see this code? A specific tag could be useful here.

Comment: This is not a C++ question but a Windows one, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-text) for example.

Comment: You should probably read the [actual Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/msiquery/nf-msiquery-msigetpropertya) instead of this weird copy site anyway.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-text   (although that is not really very good documentation IMO)

Comment: @dxiv Thank you very much, What is the difference between TEXT("Hello") and _T("Hello")?

Comment: @alancc `TEXT` decides based on the existence of `UNICODE` , whereas `_T` decides based on the existence of `_UNICODE`

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953025/why-both-unicode-and-unicode

Comment: @alancc Mostly style and context, see for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074579/should-i-use-t-or-text-on-c-string-literals) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314552/why-are-there-different-text-like-macros-for-the-same-thing-in-win32).

Comment: Don't use either. Target Unicode and use `L"xxx"` there's no point trying to support ANSI today

Comment: The code snippet is wrong, it doesn't compile. The 3rd argument needs to be a mutable character array. A string literal is immutable.

Comment: @IInspectable, This is a special usage of the function, to get the required size of the buffer. See the link I provided for more detailed info.

Comment: Your programming language doesn't know, that the API in question doesn't write through the pointer you passed given the circumstances. It simply will not compile, in case the programming language is C++ (it will compile as C, though).